# Type converter to mimic ReSharper style intellisense

Tags: c#, asp.net, intellisense

In webforms I sometimes create controls with properties like this:

```
public class Test:WebControl
{
    public Test()
    {
        Opts = new Options();
    }
    public Options Opts { get; set; }
}

public class Options
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

When this control is used in markup I get intellisense for the properties within Options. So I can type:

```
 <example:Test runat="server" Opts-Test="A" />
```

I always thought that this was default functionality within visual studio but it turns out that it is a feature of ReSharper. I believe that I could mimic this kind of functionality by creating a very complex custom type converter, but Resharper is able to provide access to these properties without me writing any custom code.

What code will fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After decompiling WebControls.Style it looks like all you need to do is:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class Options
```